# Error Oracle.DataAccess no encuentra Dll

Tags: asp.net, .net, oracle, odac

Buenos dias,

Solicito amablemente ayuda  con el siguiente error que genera mi aplicacion web en visual studio

4>C:\Users\svictorino\Documents\Confidencial y privilegiada\workspace\PCCE-V2\pcce\web.config(295): Compilar (web): No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' ni una de sus dependencias. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.

he instalado el ODAC pero genera dlls de una version mas adelantada, podrian indicarme que puedo hacer ?

Comment: ¿Qué version del .NET Framework usas? Porque parece que aun usas la versión 2. De por sí eso me llama la atención, porque eso ya es muy antiguo.

Comment: El proyecto esta en 4.0, pero en el web.config hace referencia a esa dll, es un proyecto de la universidad que quieren renovar pero primero quiero hacerlo compilar.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar redirigir la versión de tu ensamblado.
Para ello agrega lo siguiente en tu `web.config`

```
<runtime>  
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">  
      <dependentAssembly>  
        <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.DataAccess"  
       publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342"  
          culture="neutral" />  
        <!-- Assembly versions can be redirected in app,   
          publisher policy, or machine configuration files. -->  
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.112.3.0"  newVersion="<TUVERSION>" />  
      </dependentAssembly>   
    </assemblyBinding>  
  </runtime>
```